# How to create table in dojo 1.9

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am developing a sample project in Worklight which uses DOJO.In this project i am trying to generate a table in view.Initially i tried with "Datagrid" here data is not displaying properly.

js file

```
data = [
                { abbr:'ec', name:'Ecuador', capital:'Quito' },
                // ... array of data ...
            ];
            // create an object store
            var objectStore = new dojo.store.Memory({
                data: data
            });
            grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                // use the adapter to give the grid a Dojo Data compliant interface to the store
                store: dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: objectStore}),
                structure: [
                    {name:"Country", field:"name", width: "150px"},
                    {name:"Abbreviation", field:"abbr"},
                    {name:"Capital", field:"capital"}
                ]
            }, "grid");
            grid.startup();
```

html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="View1"
        data-dojo-props="selected:false,scrollDir:'v'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
            data-dojo-props="label:'Details',fixed:'top'"></div>

<div id="grid"></div>



        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
            data-dojo-props="fixed:'bottom'"></div>
    </div>
```

Here data is displaying but on top of column heading .

Is there any other way to populate table programatically in dojo.

Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that you have imported the grid css::

```
/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get dgrid at github.com.
dgrid is a lightweight, mobile-ready, data-driven, modular grid widget designed for use with the Dojo object store
It has many examples, you can get it soon.